# Enueue script for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie building a wp-blog based on a Bootstrap theme and want to enable JS – and I don't get it to work. This is my code in the functions.php :

```
function twentySven_register_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentySven-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentySven_register_scripts' );
```

This is my file structure:

`themes/twentySven/assets/js/script.js`

This is the error message
[image]

I need to register the **bootstrap related js which is in the HTML fetched via cdn**, placed in the footer:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**I can't figure out how to register these: bootstrap js and custom js.**

Thank you for your help

Comment: are you sure it's `script.js` and not `scripts.js`? `scripts.js` is referenced in the error messages, but your code that you shared has `script` not `scripts`. I tried fixing some of the formatting in your question that had broken by editing it. Is this a normal WordPress install or are you trying to change the URLs of things or use a bespoke structure such as Roots/Bedrock/Sage? ( you' know if you had done this because you would have actively chosen it ). I ask because the URLs it's failing to load are not correct, I expected to see `wp-content/themes/twentySven/assets`, not `blog/assets`

Comment: Hi Tom, Yes, I am sure: "script" not "scripts". And I did not use the mentioned structures. I totally agree, I would expect the same path. Thanks for the edit, cheers,

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, you want to get javascript bootstrap via CDN. Try to make it like in the example below. Other scripts you should attach according to this example. You must note your custom scripts should be attached after the bootstrap script if they would be using the bootstrap scripts.

```
function enqueue_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), '5.1.3', true );
  // Here you can enqueue your custom scripts
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_js' );
```